# Show / Hide Fields Using Radio Buttons in PHP Based Dynamic Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I want to show / hide my dropdown field against each selection of my radio button:

HTML & PHP

```
<?php $Sr = 1; $FPSTopics = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");
  for($i=0; $i< $FPSData = mysqli_fetch_array($FPSTopics); $i++){
 ?>
<tr>
<td style="min-width:50px;"><?php echo $Sr; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $FPSData['PFS_topic']; ?>"  readonly required="required" size="58" ></td>
 
<input type="hidden" name="FPSTopic[]" value="<?php echo $FPSData['PFS_topic_id']; ?>" />
<td style="min-width:50px;text-align:center; font-weight:bold">
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="Suitability[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="Y" id="YesCheck" /> 
<label>No</label>
<input type="radio" name="Suitability[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="N" id="NoCheck" /></td>                                                    
                                                   
<td style="min-width:50px; color:blue; font-weight:bold" class="ShowPriority">
<select class="form-control my-1 mr-sm-2" id="Priority[]" name="Priority[]" >
<option selected disabled value="">Choose Priority...</option>
<option value="1">1 - High</option>
<option value="2">2 - Intermediate</option>
<option value="3">3 - Low</option>
</select>
</td>                                                    
</tr>
<?php $Sr++; } ?>
```

If One Select YES From Radio Button. The Field Of Priority should show. And if someone selects NO then the priority field should hide.

Following is my JS Code. But upon selection, it hides the whole column instead of one field.

```
           $('#NoCheck').click(function () {
                      $('.ShowPriority').hide();
                  })
                  $('#YesCheck').click(function () {
                      $('.ShowPriority').show();
                  })
```

Comment: IDs must be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: Also next time, please remove all PHP when it is not a PHP question. Click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with only relevant HTML, JavaScript and CSS

Answer (score 2):

IDs need to be unique

You likely will find this works more reliably since I navigate relative to the row

```js
$('[name^=Suitability]').on("click", function() { // any button that starts with Suitablility
  $(this).closest('tr')
    .find('.ShowPriority')
    .toggle(this.value==="Y"); // show if "Y", Hide if not
})
```

```css
.ShowPriority { display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="min-width:50px;">
      Row 1
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" value="topic" readonly required="required" size="58"></td>

    <input type="hidden" name="FPSTopic[]" value="topic" />
    <td style="min-width:50px;text-align:center; font-weight:bold">
      <label>Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Suitability1" value="Y" />
      <label>No</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Suitability1" value="N"/>
    </td>
    <td style="min-width:50px; color:blue; font-weight:bold" class="ShowPriority">
      <select class="form-control my-1 mr-sm-2" id="Priority[]" name="Priority[]">
        <option selected disabled value="">Choose Priority...</option>
        <option value="1">1 - High</option>
        <option value="2">2 - Intermediate</option>
        <option value="3">3 - Low</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="min-width:50px;">
      Row 2
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" value="topic" readonly required="required" size="58"></td>

    <input type="hidden" name="FPSTopic[]" value="topic" />
    <td style="min-width:50px;text-align:center; font-weight:bold">
      <label>Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Suitability2" value="Y" />
      <label>No</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Suitability2" value="N" />
    </td>
    <td style="min-width:50px; color:blue; font-weight:bold" class="ShowPriority">
      <select class="form-control my-1 mr-sm-2" id="Priority[]" name="Priority[]">
        <option selected disabled value="">Choose Priority...</option>
        <option value="1">1 - High</option>
        <option value="2">2 - Intermediate</option>
        <option value="3">3 - Low</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can yo please tell me how i can mark fields required and show error if value from dropdown is not selected ? i am stuck there and not able to get out

Comment: Just add `required` on the tag. And add a `please select` with value="" to the select

Comment: $('input[name*=Suitability]').click(function () {
if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val() == "Y") {
 $(this).closest("tr").find(".ShowPriority").show(); //show
$(this).closest("tr").find(".Priority").attr('required', '').attr('data-error', 'This field is required.');
$(this).closest("tr").find(".Priority").attr('data-error', error.text());
} else {
$(this).closest("tr").find('.ShowPriority').hide(); //hide
$(this).closest("tr").find(".Priority").removeAttr('required', '');
$(this).closest("tr").find(".Priority").removeAttr('data-error', error.text());
}
})

Comment: i am using this function. in this function data-error attribute is not working and now showing error if dropdown is not selected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66769501/setting-attributes-with-jquery-in-dynamic-php-form-not-working

Comment: added this question on this link.

Comment: Don’t post code in comments. Add to the question or better: ask a new question

Comment: Alright. i have shared a link with you in new question if you help me out in this code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this).val() == "Y"` to see if the radio is checked and value of checked radio is `Y` then show select else hide it.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//on click of radio button
$('input[name*=Suitability]').click(function() {
  //check  value is Y
  if ($(this).val() == "Y") {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".ShowPriority").show(); //show

  } else {
    $(this).closest("tr").find('.ShowPriority').hide(); //hide
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="min-width:50px;">
      1
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $FPSData['PFS_topic']; ?>" readonly required="required" size="58"></td>

    <input type="hidden" name="FPSTopic[]" value="<?php echo $FPSData['PFS_topic_id']; ?>" />
    <td style="min-width:50px;text-align:center; font-weight:bold">
      <label>Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Suitability[1]" value="Y" />
      <label>No</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Suitability[1]" value="N" /></td>

    <td style="min-width:50px; color:blue; font-weight:bold" class="ShowPriority">
      <select class="form-control my-1 mr-sm-2" name="Priority[]">
        <option selected disabled value="">Choose Priority...</option>
        <option value="1">1 - High</option>
        <option value="2">2 - Intermediate</option>
        <option value="3">3 - Low</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="min-width:50px;">
      2
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $FPSData['PFS_topic']; ?>" readonly required="required" size="58"></td>

    <input type="hidden" name="FPSTopic[]" value="<?php echo $FPSData['PFS_topic_id']; ?>" />
    <td style="min-width:50px;text-align:center; font-weight:bold">
      <label>Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Suitability[2]" value="Y" />
      <label>No</label>
      <input type="radio" name="Suitability[2]" value="N" /></td>

    <td style="min-width:50px; color:blue; font-weight:bold" class="ShowPriority">
      <select class="form-control my-1 mr-sm-2" name="Priority[]">
        <option selected disabled value="">Choose Priority...</option>
        <option value="1">1 - High</option>
        <option value="2">2 - Intermediate</option>
        <option value="3">3 - Low</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank You Buddy, This Words like a charm for me. Really Helpfull.

Comment: Thank you again for your kind support in this matter. i am facing an issue. How can i mark priority select tag required when it select YES and remove it when it select NO. i have tried the following code, but does not work for me.

Comment: $('input[name*=Suitability]').click(function () {
    //check if radio is checked and value is Y
              if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val() == "Y") {
                          $(this).closest("tr").find(".ShowPriority").show(); //show
                          $(this).closest("tr").find(".Priority").attr('required', '');
                      } else {
                          $(this).closest("tr").find('.ShowPriority').hide(); //hide
                          $(this).closest("tr").find(".Priority").removeAttr('required');
                      }
                  })